# React Redux - How to access a structured selector from a static function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to acces to state from a class. Let me try to tell with code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeSelectTranslations } from 'containers/App/selectors.js';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Translation extends React.Component {

    static translate(value) {
        return this.props.translations[value];
    }
}


Translation.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    translations:makeSelectTranslations(),
  });

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      dispatch,
    };
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Translation);
```

And I want to use this translation library like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import Translation from 'libraries/Translation';

export class MainPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>{Translation.translate('hello_world')}</div>
    );
  }
}

MainPage.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  MainPage: makeSelectMainPage(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage);
```

Here is my Selector

```
const selectGlobal = () => (state) => state.get('global');

const makeSelectTranslations = () => createSelector(
  selectGlobal(),
  (globalState) => globalState.get('translations')
);
```

Here is how is my translation located : 
[image]

So, my aim is using Translation.translate('hello_world') every where of my project. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

React components aims to solve User Interface implementations, but what you are trying to do feels more like a service that depends on your App's state

Remember that redux it's a state container that works decoupled from `React`, and `react-redux` helps to make them work together.

### Recomendation

---

The same way you initialize you app with `react-redux`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './components/App';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can initialize a translator service in this way:

```
import store from './store';

export default function translate(key) {
  const state = store.getState();
  const translations = state.get('global').get('translations').toJS();

  return translations[key] || `*${key}*` ;
}
```

And then use it everywhere in your components this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import translate from 'service/translate'; // wherever you put the service

class MainPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>{translate('hello_world')}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainPage;
```

> Check the Store API for further information https://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html